# Memory Management in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to angular, so maybe I'm going about this completely wrong.  I am attempting to make a treeView with angularJS directives.  The code that I have so far accomplishes this, except that there appears to be a memory leak as each time the tree view reloads it slows down, and eventually crashes the browser.

I have created the following two directives to accomplish my task `jscTreeView` and `jscTreeNode`

This [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/metalscreamer/odcf79q4/5/) has my source, it builds you a random tree, and gives you the ability to choose the amount of nodes in the tree.  If you bump that number up to a higher number, and reload several times you will notice that it progressively slows down to each time.

Any ideas on how to clean up after myself would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edit:

This [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/metalscreamer/odcf79q4/6/) is a second attempt with this one I went in a completely different direction.  It is much more efficient, and the code is more clean in my opinion.  However, this one has an issue too. periodically, and seemingly randomly on refresh of the tree this one throws an infinite digest exception.

Note: not all of the functionality that was in the former tree is in the current tree yet.  That is just because I have not programmed it yet.

Comment: I don't think the scope ever gets destroyed... I put a break point in the `element.on('remove'` thing but I couldn't get it to trigger.

Comment: I noticed the same thing, but couldn't understand why, any idea?

Comment: I've added a `template.on("remove"...` at `jscTreeNode` and things got a little better here both at speed and memory consumption, but still far from perfect.

Comment: I can't get a break point to trigger in there either.  I actually had that there and removed it because it didn't seem to be doing anything.  I meant to remove the treeview directive's destroy as well since they weren't triggering, but apparently I forgot.

Comment: did another small test... the number of active scopes explodes (it's in the hundreds after a few clicks). I don't really know how to fix it, but [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2706-always-trigger-the-destroy-event-before-removing-elements-in-angularjs-directives.htm) guy seems to have something in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll give it a read when I have a chance, hopefully it'll have some answers.

Comment: don't try to recreate something that already exists if you don't have to... https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview

Comment: @Jorg Using the advice in your link did, change some things, and may have lead to the solution with some tweeks, but it was cuising new errors.  I have updated my question though, as I think that I have found a better approach.  The new fiddler is in the updated question.

Comment: @Claies Unfortunately, my tree will have more to it than that, I was just trying to figure out the basics. But that may be a good starting point, if it's flexible enough.

Comment: the infinite digest error comes if the tree goes >= ten levels deep.

Comment: @Jorg, how do you see the number of active scopes?

Comment: I just added a function. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o7ur9p50/) and check the console... number of scopes is contained. I think you're right about the depth of the tree. It's a number you can [configure](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) though. See bottom of page.

Comment: Thank you, I think that this will do.  I did see that page in the documentation, but did not notice the configuration option in the bottom.  While this will not work with my random tree example as the depth cannot be predetermined, it should work just fine in my actual project.  Also thanks for the scope counting function, I would still like to figure out why the first attempt didn't work, and I believe that will help.

Comment: Well bumping it up definitely [works](https://jsfiddle.net/metalscreamer/odcf79q4/7/).  I may decide to stick with this solution, but this is not recommended, so I still want to try to find a solution to the first attempt.

Comment: Probably possible without the recursive directive

Comment: I got it, still using the recursive directive too, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/metalscreamer/pwkq9k3m/), thanks for all of the help @Jorg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the discussion in the comments indicates, I was creating, but never properly releasing, scopes in my tree view.  While the solution was not very easy to figure out it is actually quite an easy solution, and clarified things a lot for me.

What I needed to do was make a clone of the root scope of my tree `var newScope = scope.$new();`, I then built all of the rest of the subtrees as well as their associated nodes and compiled with the cloned scope `newScope`.  After the compile it stores the cloned scope into a variable private to the directive `lastScope = newScope;`.  When the watch property is updated, and calls back to my directive the last cloned scope is destroyed `lastScope.$destroy();`.  Destroying that cloned scope automatically destroys any child scope created beneath it (the nodes, as well as the subtrees).  A new clone of the scope is created, and the process is repeated, thanks to @Jorg's tool to count scopes, I can see that everything is being cleaned up nicely on each iteration. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/metalscreamer/pwkq9k3m/) to the solution.